Need to format the data in trino sql
I have the table FruitMarket



Fruit
Color
City




apple
red
Shimala


apple
Green
Shimal


apple
blue
Shimala


apple
yellow
Manali


grape
black
Nagpur


grape
orange
Nashik


grape
purple
Nashik


grape
white
Nagpur



Need to display the data using trino SQL in below format:
So the output table is in below format-
Fruit   fruitInfo
apple   Shimala={red,green,blue},Manali={yellow}
grape   Nagpur={black,white},Nashik={orange,purple}

I want the fruitInfo in the form of map
I tried this:
select nettingset, array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(city)))from FruitMarket;

not array_agg function is not working. I know the functions map_from_entries and element_at but dont know how to use it here

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

multimap_agg looks like a function you need:
-- sample data
WITH dataset(Fruit, Color, City) AS (
   values ('apple', 'red',  'Shimala'),
    ('apple',   'Green',    'Shimala'),
    ('apple',   'blue', 'Shimala'),
    ('apple',   'yellow',   'Manali'),
    ('grape',   'black',    'Nagpur'),
    ('grape',   'orange',   'Nashik'),
    ('grape',   'purple',   'Nashik'),
    ('grape',   'white',    'Nagpur')
)

-- query
select Fruit, multimap_agg(City, Color) fruitInfo
from dataset
group by Fruit;

Output:



Fruit
fruitInfo




apple
{Shimala=[red, Green, blue], Manali=[yellow]}


grape
{Nagpur=[black, white], Nashik=[orange, purple]}



